# Why is the transmission black at some parts/angles?

Tags: materials, transparency

I have the problem that from a certain angle my transparent material reflects black. I have set the light paths to 128 and still the surface is black. When I set Alpha to 0,9 the black part looks perfect but the rest looks to smooth then.
I thought about to add a second reflection node to improve the gloss but I wasn't able to set it up.

[image: Rubber wire]

[image]

Comment: Glossy and total light bounces as well?  Glass internal reflection registers as glossy

Comment: Are you sure this is a failure? Try a different HDRI or a different lighting. Because this face appears to be flat, it would not be abnormal for this to actually reflect a black area of the environment. ...just a guess.

Comment: @AllenSimpson yes for a try i made alle light paths to 128. Just for being sure :D 
Thank you so much for your fast replies!!

Comment: @quellenform i tried hdri rotation and several hdris. maybe your are right and i am getting stressed for no reason :D 
Also thank you very much for your fast reply!

Comment: Your problem could therefore be solved with it? That would be great! In this case it would be fantastic if you write a short answer to your question and mark it as "Accepted answer" so that it shows up as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose an unusual solution. i rendered a cryptomatte and layered the cable twice with screen in post-production. I then masked the upper one with the cryptomatte and adjusted the desired intensity with the opacity. The solution worked out even though it wasn't a clean way :D